# How to map array of values to an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to convert the following array to an array of objects:

```
let arr = ['tree', 'apple', 'orange']
```

to

```
arr = [
  {value: tree},
  {value: apple},
  {value: orange}
]
```

My solution so far is:

```
let temp = []; 
arr.forEach(x => {   
   temp.push({value: p}); 
});

arr = temp
```

how do I solve this problem with the array.map() functionality so I can just call

```
arr.map()...
```

Comment: `arr.map(value => ({value}))`

Comment: `arr.map(o => ({value: o}))`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this with [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const arr = ['tree', 'apple', 'orange'];

const result = arr.map(value => ({ value }));

console.log(result);
```

Or more explicitly, with no implicit return or object shorthand notation:

```js
const arr = ['tree', 'apple', 'orange'];

const result = arr.map(x => {
  return { value: x };
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you return from the `.map` callback will be the new item in the array at that index - so, just replace your `temp.push(` with `return`:

```js
let arr = ['tree', 'apple', 'orange'];
arr = arr.map(x => {
  return { value: x };
});
console.log(arr);
```

Or, to implicitly return from the arrow function for more conciseness:

```js
let arr = ['tree', 'apple', 'orange'];
arr = arr.map(x => ({ value: x }));
console.log(arr);
```

(for code clarity, you might consider *not* overwriting `arr` though - assign to a new variable name instead, if you can, that way `arr` can be a `const`)

Comment: isn't there a way to directly manipulate the array without assignment?

Comment: You could reassign each index: `arr[i] = ({ value: arr[i] })`, but both reassignment and mutation are better avoided when not necessary

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.map(p => 
 {   
   return {value: p}; 
 })
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

You can use this on `arr` to get the updated array:

```js
let arr = ['tree', 'apple', 'orange'];
let arrOfObjects = arr.map( el => { return { value: el } })

console.log(arrOfObjects);
```

Comment: Please describe what did you change and why, to help others identify the problem and understand this answer!

Answer (score 0):

**Map is pure** it will not change your target or parent array. Map creates it's own copy of array and returns results by doing operations on copied array.

```js
let arr = ['tree', 'apple', 'orange'];
 
console.log(arr.map(x => ({ value: x })));
```