# How to convert array to object with add same key in this object Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to convert this array to object with same custom key

```
let array=['a','b','c']
 let y=    Object.assign({}, [...array]);
```

I want resualt like this

```
[{'name':'a'},{'name':'b'},{'name':'c'}]
```

how I can do this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to map array of values to an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55512028/how-to-map-array-of-values-to-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Array.map. Here it is.

```js
let array=['a','b','c']
const res = array.map(item => ({name: item}))
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why haven't you tried a simple for loop yet:

```js
let array=['a','b','c']
let ans = []; //initialize empty array
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){ //iterate over initial array
ans.push({name : array[i]}); //push in desired format 
}
console.log(ans);
```

Answer (score 0):

For example. With `map()` or loops like `for...` or `forEach` you can do it.

```js
array=['a','b','c']

let res1 = array.map(a => ({name: a}))
console.log('map()', res1)

// or forEach

let res2 = [];
array.forEach(a => {
  res2.push( {name: a})
})

console.log('forEach()', res2)
```